# CSS hover isn't working (needed to show up underline)

Tags: css, hover

I guess i have some mistake and my eyes cant find problem. So i am asking you to help me find my problem - underline dont show up on hover.

Fiddle you can find by fidle net slash t4fmuxbL (because of this stupid editor)

```css
body, div, span, ul, li {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-family:"Agency FB";
}

li, a {
 list-style-type:none;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 font-size:14px;
}

li {
 display:inline-block;
 margin:28.5px 5px 5px 35px;
}

.underline-div {
 border-top:3px solid #FFB700;
 width:12px;
 float:left;
 margin-left:41px;
 margin-top:-3px;
 display:none;
}

#und-div2 {
 margin-left:56px;
 width:22px;
}

#und-div3 {
 margin-left:56px;
 width:18px;
}

#und-div4 {
 margin-left:55px;
 width:36px;
}

#news:hover #und-div1 {
 display:block;
}

#forums:hover #und-div2 {
 display:block;
}

#blogs:hover #und-div3 {
 display:block;
}

#statistics:hover #und-div4 {
 display:block;
}



.page, .header {
 padding:0;
}

.page {
 border:1px solid black;
 height:1200px;
 min-width:1265px;
 width:100%;
}

.header-bg {
 height:655px;
 border:1px solid black;
 background:url("http://pokkers.lv/photo-bg.jpg");
 background-size:cover;
}

nav {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:75px;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.main-nav {
 width:380px;
 height:75px;
}

.left-nav{
 margin-left:200px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
}

.right-nav {
 margin-right:200px;
 float:right;
}

.side-div {
 border:1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class = "col-md-12 page">
   <header class = "col-md-12 header">
    <div class = "header-bg">
     <nav>
      <div class = "left-nav main-nav">
       <ul>
        <li id = "news"><a href = "#">NEWS</a></li>
        <li id = "forums"><a href = "#">FORUMS</a></li>
        <li id = "blogs"><a href = "#">BLOGS</a></li>
        <li id = "statistics"><a href = "#">STATISTICS</a></li>
       </ul>
       <div class = "underline-div" id = "und-div1">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class = "underline-div" id = "und-div2">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class = "underline-div" id = "und-div3">&nbsp;</div>
       <div class = "underline-div" id = "und-div4">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div class = "right-nav main-nav">
       <ul>
        <li><a href = "#">SERVERS</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">BANLIST</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">MARKET</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#">CONTACTS</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </header>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: You can embed the fiddle in this stupid editor as well.

Answer (score 1):

You must add 
text-decoration: underline;
to hover of items

Comment: This doesn't answer the specifics of the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why you're using new `<div>` elements as an underline, but to get to the point:

It is impossible to select those divs with a hover in your current HTML structure.

Why don't you add a simple `text-decoration: underline` to the initial `<li>` whenever you hover it? You can can then simply address the `<a>` tag, I've updated your code here:

```css
body, div, span, ul, li {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-family:"Agency FB";
}

li, a {
 list-style-type:none;
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
 font-size:14px;
}

li {
 display:inline-block;
 margin:28.5px 5px 5px 35px;
}

li a:hover {
 border-bottom:3px solid #FFB700;
}

.page, .header {
 padding:0;
}

.page {
 border:1px solid black;
 height:1200px;
 min-width:1265px;
 width:100%;
}

.header-bg {
 height:655px;
 border:1px solid black;
 background:url("http://pokkers.lv/photo-bg.jpg");
 background-size:cover;
}

nav {
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:75px;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.main-nav {
 width:380px;
 height:75px;
}

.left-nav{
 margin-left:200px;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
}

.right-nav {
 margin-right:200px;
 float:right;
}

.side-div {
 border:1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class = "col-md-12 page">
  <header class = "col-md-12 header">
   <div class = "header-bg">
    <nav>
     <div class = "left-nav main-nav">
      <ul>
       <li id = "news"><a href = "#">NEWS</a></li>
       <li id = "forums"><a href = "#">FORUMS</a></li>
       <li id = "blogs"><a href = "#">BLOGS</a></li>
       <li id = "statistics"><a href = "#">STATISTICS</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class = "right-nav main-nav">
      <ul>
       <li><a href = "#">SERVERS</a></li>
       <li><a href = "#">BANLIST</a></li>
       <li><a href = "#">MARKET</a></li>
       <li><a href = "#">CONTACTS</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </header>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Use a `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element to mimic this?

Comment: I tried, but had wrong effects (lines show up in different places). In fact i never did that before and not sure how to... Just read in stack that there is option with other divs...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could accomplish this using :after pseudo elements, as the current HTML structure you have won't allow for you to hover on a link, and reveal a div (or any other element) that isn't a child of that `<a>`

CSS:

```
  .main-nav a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none
  }

  .main-nav a:after {
    content: '';
    display: none;
    height: 2px;
    background: #f00;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
  }

  .main-nav a:hover:after,
  .main-nav a:focus:after {
    display: block;
  }
```

Demo HTML

```
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#!">
      Link
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Works perfect.